# I can't boot into my UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: partition, fstab, fsck

[image: This is what is showing up when trying to boot into my UNUNTU 20.04 LTS. It's stuck in Emergency Mode. Please someone help]

some problem in partition /dev/sda8 and it has logged me into emergency Mode. I tried running fsck command but to any use and also commented the fstab file but none worked. Please help me !

Comment: Edit `/etc/fstab` and comment out the entry and reboot. It should boot normally, then you can start diagnosing what has gone wrong with that partition. Perhaps its mount point has disappeared.

Comment: @Bib how to comment out the entry ? Can you show pics of fstab file?

Comment: Just run vi on  it and put a `#` at the start of the offending line.